# RecylerView does not show all the elements

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have this RecyclerView and when I add something on a fab button, more exactly a note, it comes above the one already added.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

        
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/notes_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also, I have tried in another way to make the RecyclerView, like this:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/notes_list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />
```

but unfornatunately it does not work.

This is how I have the database created

```
@Dao
public interface NotesDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE) 
    void insertNote(Note note);

    @Delete
    void deleteNote(Note note); 

    @Update
    void updateNote(Note note);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM notes")
    List<Note> getNotes();
    

    @Query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE id = :noteId") 
    Note getNodeById(int noteId);

@Query("DELETE FROM notes WHERE id = :noteId") 
    void deleteNotesById(int noteId);
}
```

and this is how I add a new note:

```
if (!text.isEmpty()) {
            long date = new Date().getTime(); 
            
            temp.setNoteDate(date);
            temp.setNoteText(text);

            if (temp.getId() == -1) {
                dao.insertNote(temp); 
            } else {
                dao.updateNote(temp);
            }

            finish(); 
        }
```

Can you tell me what do I have to change in order to see all the notes (one below the other)?

Comment: Could you check you list size in recyclerview adapter and height of recyclerview_item.xml must bw wrap_content.

Comment: The height recyclerview_item.xml is wrap_content and the list is declared like this `private ArrayList<Note> notes;` so its size depends on the note; I do not know what to modify

Comment: just try to print the size of the list , that you fetched is the expected or not.

Comment: I get [] when I try to print it